# Converting coordinates on google earth

Tags: navigation, gps, gis, google-earth

I have coordinates on an excel sheet that are expressed as follows:

```
Latitude             Longitude
16,5037993382 -25,0139206899
```

- whole part are degrees,
- first two decimals are minutes,
- decimals 3 and 4 are seconds, the rest fraction of seconds.

Example:

```
16,5037993382          shall be read 16º50'3799''N
-25,0139206899          shall be read 025º01'3920''W
```

After I import the .csv to Google earth I have this: [image: see image]

The point should be located near the red cross.

I need to somehow be able to import this data to google earth, or a tool to convert it if possible.

Comment: Do no link images. Either include in the question (if the image is really needed), or just copy the text. Programmers will not open random links from random people. Are you sure about how to read angles? Usually it is not done so. Either you have explicit prime and seconds until the decimal point. Then it is decimal. In such case I assume it is just decimal of a degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Earth does not know how to decode the "16,5037993382" format for coordinates as you described above.

Google Earth supports longitude and latitude as Degrees-Minutes-Seconds (DMS) in the following forms:

1. **Use a single quote for minutes and a double quote for seconds:**
   Example: 49 7'20.06"
2. **Direction notation (North/South, East/West):**
   Use N, S, E, or W to indicate direction.
   Example: N 37 24 23.3 or 37 24 23.3 N
3. **Use the minus sign (-) for western or southern positions: When you use this, do not specify a letter.**
   Example: 37 25 19.07, -122 05 08.40
   Note: Don’t use a plus sign (+) for northerly/easterly directions.

All 3 forms of the coordinate represented in DMS are depicted in this CSV example. If you change your CSV file to one of these formats then Google Earth Pro will correctly import it.

```
Latitude,Longitude
"16 50'37.993382""N","25 01'39.206899""W"
"N 16 50 37.993382","W 25 01 39.206899"
"16 50 37.993382","-25 01 39.206899"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code looks like it does the right thing:

```py
import re
from math import copysign

def dms_to_decimal(text):
    m = re.match(r'^([-+]?[0-9]+),([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]+)$', text)
    if not m:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported format")
    deg, min, sec, frac = m.groups()
    deg = float(deg)
    min = float(min)
    sec = float(f"{sec}.{frac}")
    return deg + copysign(min / 60 + sec / 3600, deg)

def parse_lat_lon(text):
    lat, lon = text.split()
    return dms_to_decimal(lat), dms_to_decimal(lon)

lat, lon = parse_lat_lon('16,5037993382 -25,0139206899')
print(f"{lat:.6f},{lon:.6f}")
```

Outputs: `16.843887,-25.027557`

Which you can check with: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/16.843887,-25.027557

If you have lots of these values, I'd suggest converting them to decimal coordinates as Google Earth and most other programs tend to be happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data's alrady in an Excel spreadsheet, you can use Excel to manipulate your data into a simple floating point number of degrees that Google Earth will read. The end result will look like this:
[image]

| Test coordinate | degrees | digits(minutes) | digits (whole seconds) | digits(fractional seconds) | decimal coordinate degrees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | =FLOOR(D6,1) | =FLOOR(D6,0.01)-E6 | =FLOOR(D6,0.0001)-SUM(E6+F6) | =D6-SUM(E6:G6) | =E6+((F6*100)/60)+((G6*10000)/60/60)+((H6*10000)/60/60) |
| Check multipliers in I5 |  | =F6*100 | =G6*10000 | =H6*10000 |  |

Row 7 in the picture is just to check that the decimal points were setup correctly and can be removed. The forumlas are included in the table above. Make a set of these formulas for each of the coordinates (I'm guessing ther lat and lng) in each row. Google Earth will read coordinate degrees.